# Where does oxygen come from in winters?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, photosynthesis, plant-anatomy

Since plants shed their leaves and don't perform photosynthesis during winters, where does oxygen come from?

Comment: 1-There is a lot of oxygen. Certainly enough to last the winter. 2- Equatorial rainforests don't lose their leaves as the seasons are less severe. 3- The Taiga forest in Russia and the Boreal forest of Canada have evergreens which also do not lose their leaves.

Comment: 4 - Generally "winter" is not "winter" at the same time everywhere on the world.

Comment: Oceans are the largest producer of oxygen

Comment: As others have pointed out, it's not winter everywhere at the same time, and there's a lot more oxygen than would be used up in one winter.  However, if you look up "Keeling Curve", you can see the annual variation in CO2 (and hence O2, inversely) due to winter in the northern hemisphere.  It seems to be on the order of 6 ppm.

Comment: These all look like answers to the question.